# How do I show that the relation $R : \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{Q}$ defined by $R((a/b, c/d)) = ((a+c) / (b+d))$ is not a function?

Tags: functions, relations

I don't understand how to establish the relation 
$$R ((a/b, c/d)) = ((a+c) / (b+d))$$

Comment: Did you mean to write this as a ternary relation $R\subset \Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$

Comment: Are you trying to say that $\frac ab \sim \frac cd$ if and only if $\frac ab + \frac cd = \frac{a+c}{b + d}$.  Otherwise, you are, in effect, saying $\frac ab \sim \frac cd$ if and only if $\frac{a+c}{b+d}...?...$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen its written correctly as is

Comment: @amWhy thats how i thought it should be but the problem is as i wrote it

Comment: I would take $R$ to represent a binary operator  $\star$, with $a/b \in \mathbb Q$ and $c/d \in\mathbb  Q$ such that  $\frac ab \star \frac cd = \frac{a+c}{b+d}$. The point is it fails to be a function (see below)

Comment: So $$R : \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}, \quad R ((a/b, c/d)) = \frac ab \star \frac cd  = ((a+c) / (b+d))$$  Now, Suppose, for $a/b, c/d,$ with $\frac ab = \frac 13 = \frac 26 = \frac {2a}{2b}$, we get $\frac ab\star \frac cd = \frac{a+c}{b+d},$ while $\frac {2a}{2b} \star \frac cd = \frac{2a + c}{2b + d}$.

Comment: @Skatee Then (me nitpicking) the question should rather read "How do I show that one cannot define a function $R\colon\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ such that $R((a/b,c/d))=((a+c)/(b+d))$?" or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy approach is just to say, let $a=1,c=1,b=1,d=-1$. Then $R(\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{-1})=\frac{1+1}{1-1}$ which is undefined.

However, you'll learn more through observing that $R$ is not even well defined, by which I mean that you can give the same argument to $R$ twice, and get different results. Since you have no canonical form for the argument, you could input $\frac{1}{2}$ as $\frac{2}{4}$. However, $R(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{1})=\frac{1+1}{2+1}=\frac{2}{3}$. This is not the same as $R(\frac{2}{4},\frac{1}{1})=\frac{2+1}{4+1}=\frac{3}{5}$ even though $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{1})=(\frac{2}{4},\frac{1}{1})$, so $R$ is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(\frac ab,\frac cd)\in \Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$ is the same point as $(\frac ab, \frac{2c}{2d})$. As such, if $R$ were a well-defined function, it should give the same result for them both. But it doesn't.

Try, for instance, with $a=b=d=1$ and $c=2$, which gives the value $\frac32$ in the first case, and $\frac 53$ in the other.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a function, because it is ill-defined as a map from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

For instance, $R(1/2,0/2) = 1/4$, while $R(2/4,0/2) = 1/3$ --- but $(1/2,0/2) = (2/4,0/2)$ in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, so it is ill-defined where this element is supposed to map to.

Answer (score 0):

$R(a/b, c/d) \ne R((na)/(nb), c/d)$
even though
$a/b = (na)/(nb)$.

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If something is a function then it cannot has two (or more) different values at one point.

Now suppose $a=\frac{1}{2}, ~b=\frac{1}{1}$ and you obtain $R(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{1}) = \frac{2}{3}$, but then take arguments $a=\frac{2}{4}$ $b=\frac{1}{1}$ (that is definitely the same) and the value of this "function" becomes $R(\frac{2}{4},\frac{1}{1}) = \frac{3}{5}$.